# ios UIDocumentPickerViewController is not remembering last folder

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have a pretty simple swift code to open Files app and let the user browse to any folder and pick a file.

```
func goToFilesApp() {
    
    var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        let types: [UTType] = [UTType.text,
                               UTType.vCard,
                               UTType.zip,
                               UTType.gzip]
        documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: types)
    } else {
        let types = [String(kUTTypeText),
                     String(kUTTypeVCard),
                     "com.pkware.zip-archive",
                     "org.gnu.gnu-zip-archive",
                     "org.gnu.gnu-zip-tar-archive"]
        documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types, in: .import)
    }
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    if let view = self.view as? UIViewController {
        
        view.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and

```
extension AnalyzeFilePresenter : UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

  func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    
      if let firstUrl = urls.first {
        manageFilePicked(url: firstUrl)
      }
    }
}
```

This is working well, but users use this feature very often and under some circumstances the Files app is not remembering the last folder and the user has to browse to their last location (which is a bit annoying).

With my iPhone X, ios 15.3.1 and iCloud unactive, this code remembers the last folder accessed.

With my iPhone 13 Pro, iOS 16.2 and iCloud active, this code doesn't remember the last folder accessed and instead show a default folder.
With this iPhone 13, if the user uses Files app (outside of my app) Files app indeed remembers the last folder, so I guess it's a problem of my app.

What could I try? Because every SO answer I've read show this little piece of code I'm using.

Comment: Could you not remember the user's last location and open the document picker at that location later ?

Comment: I tried to do this but I couldn't find how to do it.